# Degenerate solution in linear programming

Tags: linear-programming

How can I determine if a solution in a linear programming problem is degenerate without I use any software or the graphical display of the solution;

For example in the model:

$$\max\{2x_1 + 4x_2\}\\\phantom{ aa}\\
    \text{s.t.}\\\phantom{a}\\\begin{array}{rr}
    x_1 + 2x_2 & \leq 5\\
    x_1 + x_2 & \leq 4\\
    x_1 &\geq 0\\
    x_2 &\geq 0 \end{array}$$

The variable $x_1$ takes the value $0$ but Ι think the solution is not degenerate. Specifically, the solution is $x_1 = 0$, $x_2 = 2.5$, $S_1 = 0$, $S_2 = 0$.

Comment: If there are 2 distinct points in a space , for which the LPP is optimum, then all the points on the line joining the points  and in between them , will serve as a optimum solution.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Please consider learning LaTeX / mathjax typesetting. It will make questions and answers more readable by all participants. I assumed the $S_1$ and $S_2$ are slack variables. Is this the case?

Answer (score 3):

An Linear Programming is degenerate if in a basic feasible solution, one of the basic variables takes on a zero value. Degeneracy is caused by redundant constraint(s), e.g. see [this example](https://advol.cas.mcmaster.ca/feng/4O03/LP.Degeneracy.pdf).

Comment: I edited my question for more details

Comment: Link broken, correct version: https://advol.cas.mcmaster.ca/feng/4O03/LP.Degeneracy.pdf

Comment: @MilindR Thank you - corrected.

Answer (score 0):

The above question is not degenerate since if you work out this by simplex method, $X_1$ is not a basic variable so it can take a value $>=0$. In the final tablue, the solution could be degenerate if either $X_2$ or $S_2$ was equal to 0